# Azure Devops Server - what is a work item "processbehavior"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2022

I am trying to get some information on Azure Devops Work Item Behaviors and not seeing a description of what it does.

This link really doesn't say anything useful other than how to list/get/create:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/behaviors/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

I can download a work item states, rules, and layout but I would like to understand what the behavior actually does.

How are behaviors different from rules and states?

I can download the behaviors and I see System.*, Microsoft.VSTS.*, and a few Custom.* behaviors.  There is a brief description, rank, ... other fields but that does not explain what a behavior actually does.